# How to check the convergence of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty ({ a^{1/n} - \frac{b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}}{2}}),\ if (a>0,b>0,c>0)$

> Edit 1
>
> Sorry, replaced i with n. Obviously, term test is inconclusive
>   due to limit is equal to zero. Actually, i tried ratio test several
>   times but didn't succeed and got 1 as a result every time. Also tried
>   to represent a,b,c as exponents and expand them in Taylor series but
>   it didn't work too.

Comment: Theres no $i$ in the summands

Comment: you'll get a better chance to receive an answer and will not risk your post to be closed, if you share here what you have tried with the problem.

Comment: @user2942898: The question seems fine, but you just need to show your thought.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^{1/n}=1+\frac{\ln(x)}{n} + O(n^{-2})$.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on how did you expand exponential function into series?
As far as i know exp.func can't be expanded in such form due to the fact that each term in Maclaurin series will have $x^{1/0}$

Comment: $x^{1/n}=e^{\ln(x)/n}=1+\ln(x)/n +O(n^{-2})$. In my expansion, $x$ is fixed and the variable term is $n$.

Comment: I'm sorry for slowness but still didn't catch it. Using ratio test, ignoring the remainder term get 1 again:
$\lim_{x \to \inf}\frac{2+2\left(\frac{ln(a)}{n+1}\right)-1-\left(\frac{ln(b)}{n+1}\right)-1-\left(\frac{ln(c)}{n+1}\right)}{2+2\left(\frac{ln(a)}{n}\right)-1-\left(\frac{ln(b)}{n}\right)-1-\left(\frac{ln(c)}{n}\right)}=
\frac{2ln(a)-ln(b)-ln(c)}{2ln(a)-ln(b)-ln(c)}*\frac{n}{n+1}=1$

Comment: X obviously should be replaced with n in limit.

Comment: Apart from the obvious division by $0$ issue that you seemingly did not notice, why on earth would you bother with a ratio test given an expansion in $\alpha/n+O(n^{-2})$ of the term of your series?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's a lot @Mindlack for help. For all who didn't understand above-stated hint here is the solution:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ({ a^{1/n} - \frac{b^{1/n}+c^{1/n}}{2}})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(e^{\frac{ln(a)}{n}}-\frac{e^{\frac{ln(b)}{n}}+e^{\frac{ln(c)}{n}}}{2})$
Expanding exponential function as Mclaurin series and using the logarithm properties:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2+2\left(\frac{ln(a)}{n}\right)-(1+\left(\frac{ln(b)}{n}\right)+1+\left(\frac{ln(c)}{n}\right))+O(n^{-2}))}{2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{ln(\frac{a^2}{bc})}{2n}+O(n^{-2})$
The second term of sum converges everywhere while the first term is harmonic series which diverges everywhere except $a=\sqrt{bc}$.
Answer: diverges everywhere except $a=\sqrt{bc}$.